# Looking for a Combo(Viewer) in SWT/JFace which supports autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, swt, jface, type-ahead

I'm looking for a Combo(Viewer) in SWT/JFace which supports autocomplete / type-ahead, i.e. the user can enter a couple of characters and the drop down list should show all matching elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also check out the `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` class.  It's not a combo, just a text field, but it adds auto complete functionality as if it were a combo very easily. You can do something as simple as this:

```
Text textField = new Text(parentComposite, SWT.BORDER);
new AutoCompleteField(textField, new TextContentAdapter(), new String[] 
    {"autocomplete option 1", "autocomplete option 2"});
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is anything like this built into either Combo or ComboViewer.

As thehiatus suggests `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` is probably the best place to look for this, however, there is support for Combos:

```
new AutoCompleteField(combo, new ComboContentAdapter(), new String[] 
    {"item0", "item1"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in Eclipse's **"Content Assist"** feature.  You can see it in action when using the Eclipse IDE's Java editor.  As you edit source code, you will sometimes see a drop-down menu with phrases that complete what you were typing.  (Note that you can press **Ctrl+Space** to force the drop-down menu to be displayed.)

You can implement this in your own SWT/JFace application as well.  The "[Java Developer's Guide to Eclipse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321305027)" has an sample application that implements Content Assist.  The sample application is a SQL editor, and it is described in Chapter 26, "Building a Custom Text Editor with JFace Text."  There's actually an online overview of the chapter [here](http://www.jdg2e.com/jdg2e_CD_for_eclipse321/documentation/html/ch26.jface.text/doc/index.html).  The sample SQL editor project, `com.ibm.jdg2e.editor.jfacetext.sql`, can be found [here](http://www.jdg2e.com/jdg2e_CD_for_eclipse321/plug-in_development/examples/com.ibm.jdg2e.editor.jfacetext.sql/).

On the other hand, if you want to create your own Combo widget and auto-populate it based on input that is being entered, then this might not be very applicable.  I'm thinking the `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer` might be helpful (though I'm not positive).

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtaddons/

I use it in my project (with a little tweak).

Answer (score 1):

It's really dead easy to set this up.

As thanks to paz117's comment, thought I'd share the code to make this work:

```
String[] proposals = new String[controller.model().size()];

for (int i = 0; i < controller.model().size(); i++) 
    proposals[i] = controller.model().get(i).getAppropriateName();

comboViewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.NONE);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
comboViewer.setLabelProvider(new AppropriateLabelProvider());
comboViewer.setInput(_controller.model());
// additionally, configure the comboViewer arbitrary
new AutoCompleteField(comboViewer.getCombo(), new ComboContentAdapter(), proposals);
```

The only minor nuisance is that you have to separately populate the model of ComboViewer and AutoCompleteField separately, but that can be at least automated via a static utility method or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As reference for future visitors, the [AutocompleteComboInput](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/downloads.sourceforge.net/s/sw/swtaddons/swtaddons/SWT%20Add-ons%200.1.1/SWTAddons-Documentation-0.1.1.html) (SWT Add-on), can also be a way to achieve this.

[image: AutocompleteComboInput]

Code snippet for screenshot (refer to documentation link above for the code template):

```
import net.sf.swtaddons.autocomplete.combo.AutocompleteComboInput;
...

subjectCodeCombo = new Combo(tab3Composite, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
// other code modifying Combo appearance here...

// returns a String[] of items retrieved from database
String[] subjectCodeArray = dbQuery.subjectsToArray();

subjectCodeCombo.setItems(subjectCodeArray);
subjectCodeCombo.setText("- SELECT -");
new AutocompleteComboInput(subjectCodeCombo);
```

The add-on requires all JARs below to be added to the Library: ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854005/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-using-swt-add-on-autocompletecomboinput))

- eclipse-equinox-common-3.5.0.jar
- net.sf.swtaddons_0.1.1_bin_src.jar ([sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtaddons/files/swtaddons/SWT%20Add-ons%200.1.1/))
- org.eclipse.core.commands.jar
- org.eclipse.jface-3.6.0.jar

Click [here](https://app.box.com/s/yrsdaubcisqtkqw828g4) for JAR pack.