# I need a SWT file chooser dialog with auto suggestion combo

Tags: java, swt

I need a SWT file chooser dialog with auto suggestion combo. Example : When user edit the combo area as C:\ then all the sub directories in the C should be displayed and when user enter C:\Pr , then all the folders starting with Pr should be listed/Suggested in combo items

Comment: SWT uses native OS widgets.Thus `FileDialog` behaviour is different on different OS. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069304/looking-for-a-comboviewer-in-swt-jface-which-supports-autocomplete)

Basically when the user types a path (and it's valid), you use other Java APIs to fetch subdirectories, then add them as proposals to your `AutoCompleteField`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is while user type the directory and try to enter some character then all the subdirectories/folders starting with that character need to be displayed to user.So how to achieve this trough the code, Please provide some example programs for same.

Comment: @Kaaru That is exactly what I've explained in my answer... I'll make an effort and post some code later on today. Please try and see how content proposals work til then. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah dude thanks,i am also working on it with may approaches need to see which one works out as expected...