# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using SWT Add-on (AutocompleteComboInput)

Tags: java, swt, classpath, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to implement an autocomplete Combo in SWT using [AutocompleteComboInput](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/downloads.sourceforge.net/s/sw/swtaddons/swtaddons/SWT%20Add-ons%200.1.1/SWTAddons-Documentation-0.1.1.html). I have added [net.sf.swtaddons_0.1.1_bin_src.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtaddons/files/swtaddons/SWT%20Add-ons%200.1.1/) to the library via "Add External JAR".

```
import net.sf.swtaddons.autocomplete.combo.AutocompleteComboInput;
...

subjectCodeCombo = new Combo(tab3Composite, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
// other code modifying Combo appearance here...

// returns a String[] of items retrieved from database
String[] subjectCodeArray = dbQuery.subjectsToArray();

subjectCodeCombo.setItems(subjectCodeArray);
subjectCodeCombo.setText("- SELECT -");
new AutocompleteComboInput(subjectCodeCombo); // throws an error
```

However, I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError`. As I have read, it seems [a class is not found during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java).

I believe I need to do something about the "runtime classpath", but I am lost. Steps on how to resolve this in Eclipse IDE is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem.

Apart from `net.sf.swtaddons_0.1.1_bin_src.jar`, 3 other JARs were still needed to be added to the Library:

- eclipse-equinox-common-3.5.0.jar
- org.eclipse.core.commands.jar
- org.eclipse.jface-3.6.0.jar